# Feature Matching + Homography to find objects

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv to take in a query image and match it within a base image. I looked at the online tutorials, and lo and behold, they had example code to do just that. So I copied and pasted the code and tried to run it with a few trial images. Here's the code and a sample set of images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread('10hearts.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('example.jpg',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0 
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50) 

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
                    good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
        matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

        h,w = img1.shape
        pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

        img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
        print "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
        matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
                    singlePointColor = None,
                    matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                    flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)

plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

Here's my query image:
[image]

The image in which I'm searching:
[image: Base Image]

Unfortunately, the code to visualize the results never works. Whenever I run it, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

I did some simple debugging, and  everything seems fine until the findHomography() call, which returns Null, Null.  Any suggestions what might be wrong? I download opencv according to the following instructions, just in case this might be the problem: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Usually a zero matrix results means, it couldn't find any homography. Might help you to use more points. Especially if you use ransac, because this ignores outliers, so who knows if it sees all points as those

Comment: That seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SIFT you can use [Brute-Force Matching with ORB Descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html).

You'll get some extra points, if you change `matches[:10]` to `matches[:20]` or `matches`.

You can use your

```
if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
```

loop in this code.